# Objeto que tiene como atributo una lista en la cual se almacena objetos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pycharm

Tengo un clase llamada "Vol' en la cual unos de sus atributos es un lista llamada 'seients' y tengo un método en el cual añade el asiento al atributo lista del objeto.

```
class Vol():
    def __init__(self):
        self.codi = None
        self.data = None
        self.companyia = None
        self.tipus_avio = None
        self.desti = None
        self.origen = None
        self.seients = []

    def pintaDades(self):
        print("codi: ", self.codi)
        print("data: ", self.data)
        print("companyia: ", self.company)
        print("tipo de avio: ", self.tipo_avion)
        print("desti: ", self.desti)
        print("origen: ", self.origen)

    def inicialitzaTeclat(self):  # lo mismo que creaVol() de la practica 1
        self.codi = str(input("Introduce Codi: "))
        self.data = self.comprovarData(str(input("Introduce data: ")))
        while not self.data:  # entrara en el bucle siempre y cuando data= TRUE, y se debera repetir otra vez el ingreso de la variable
            self.data = str(input("Introduce data: "))  # data=comprovarData(str(input("Introduce data:")))
            self.data = self.comprovarData(self.data)
        self.company = str(input("Introduce Companyia: "))
        self.tipo_avion = str(input("Introduce tipo de Avion: "))
        self.desti = str(input("Introduce destino: "))
        self.origen = str(input("Introduce origeno: "))

    def afegeixSeient(self, seat):  # meter seient en la lista seients
        self.seients.append(seat)  # agrega a la lista el objeto seient ==> seients = seients +[seat]

    def pintaSeient(self):  # muestra todos los asientos del vuelo, recorrer lista
        i = 0
        if len(self.seients[:]) > 0:  # si hay algo en la lista
            while i < len(self.seients[:]):
                print(self.seients[i].fila, self.seients[i].lletra)
                i = i + 1
        else:
            print("lista de asientos vacia.")
```

además tengo otra Clase llamada 'Asiento':

```
class Seient():
        fila=None
        lletra=None

    def pintaDades(self):
        print("fila: ",self.fila)
        print("lletra: ",self.lletra)

    def inicialitzaTeclat(self):
        self.fila=str(input("Inserta fila: "))
        self.lletra=str(input("Inserta lletra: "))
```

En el Programa principal solo pondré el trozo que creo que es donde me falla de alguna manera, ya que es bastante largo, este contiene diversas funciones, en la cual esta la de 'crearVol', esta funcion básicamente crea un vuelo y si todos los atributos del vuelo son correctos pasaría añadir asientos del vuelo, el cual se añadirían en el atributo 'seient' de la clase Vol:

```
def crearVol():
    v=Vol() #intancia class Vol
    v.inicialitzaTeclat()   #metodo para introducir cosas del vuelo
    s=Seient()
    s.inicialitzaTeclat()
    v.afegeixSeient(s)       #metodo para intrudir asiento
    v.pintaDades()
    v.pintaSeient()
    opcio=(str(input("Voleu introduir un altre seient? (S/N) "))).upper()       # opcio.upper, convertimos en mayus
    while opcio[0]=="S":
        s.inicialitzaTeclat()
        v.afegeixSeient(s)       #metodo para intrudir asiento
        v.pintaDades()
        v.pintaSeient()
        opcio=(str(input("Voleu introduir un altre seient? (S/N) "))).upper()
```

El problema esta que cada vez que intrusco un asiento y se guarda en el atributo 'seient' de la clase Vol, desaparece el el primer asiento introducido y el segundo me lo añade en el índice 0 y 1 de la lista 'seient', es decir, os dejo un ejemplo ahora.

el usuario ha introducido 2 asientos en el vuelo, el primer asiento es '1A' y el segundo '2E', debo decir que el asiento tambien es una clase de tipo 'seient', por lo tanto la lista tendrá objetos 'seient'.

la lista debería tener almacenados los asiento de la siguiente manera,

```
self.seient=[<__main__.Seient object at 0x000001D223B94B70>,<__main__.Seient object at 0x000001D223B95F70>]
```

Si imprimimos los asientos deberían salir

```
>>>A1
>>>2E
```

Pero la cosa es que no me sale eso, el atributo seient, me guarda el ultimo asiento introducido en todos los índices de la lista y se pierden los otros asiento.

```
self.seient=[<__main__.Seient object at 0x000001D223B94B70>,<__main__.Seient object at 0x000001D223B94B70>]
```

si imprimimos esto, saldría.

```
>>>2E   # Este debería ser A1
>>>2E
```

Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python la inmensa mayoría de los elementos son objetos ... y estos se gestionan de forma implícita mediante punteros luego en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
s = Seient()
s2 = s
```

Ambas variables apuntan al mismo objeto.

Para evitar esto tienes que asegurarte de crear objetos nuevos cada vez:

```
while opcio[0]=="S":
    s = Seient() # Nuevo objeto
    s.inicialitzaTeclat()
    v.afegeixSeient(s)       #metodo para intrudir asiento
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ayer estuve mirándolo un par de horas y no sabia porque o que pasaba